# Show message after cancellation

Tags: notification, messages, cancel, prompt

On my website, users can create, edit and cancel event dates

Would it be weird or user-unfriendly to not serve users a message after canceling a date? (it redirects to the overview page)

I'm aiming for a somewhat minimal design. And preferably avoid static "date canceled" notices with OK button or X (close).

But maybe it could just fade away after a second or so

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide some form of feedback to the user that the event date was cancelled.

- According to Lund "Every action should have a reaction."
- Jacob Nielson's first of 10 principles of user interface design state "The system should always keep users informed about what is going on, through appropriate feedback within reasonable time."
- Alan Cooper calls out the importance of an iteration loop which provides action, *feedback*, evaluation, and reaction.

The act of redirecting to an overview page would not provide appropriate feedback that the event date was cancelled.

A common pattern is the one you mention of displaying a success message on your overview page that would read "The picnic event on 02/24/2015 has been cancelled." This message could fade away after a few seconds. Its best to test (i.e. guerrilla usability test) the message fade with a few users to determine an appropriate amount of time for the message to be properly read and understood, but not stick around longer than its needed.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to show a message, or else people won't know what happened. It could be as easy as an inlined message

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXKfBC.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You could also visually treat it so it's not even with a bounding box, but just a text. As long as they know that it was deleted (with a confirmation), you should be fine.

Comment: "or else people won't know what happened". But they just clicked CANCEL + confirmed CANCEL

Comment: In the web world, you really need to let the user know that the server actually performed the cancel.

Comment: @17of26 is correct. Even after they clicked confirmed cancel, the system might have hiccuped in between. What then? Do you not show them a message either? You need to show that, even if they confirmed it, the system actually did it.

Comment: Yes. Well I don't disagree ;) Right now the user clicks cancel, then confirms. And if anything did not work as planned the user is served an error message. But I hear ya

Answer (score 0):

**Would it be weird or user-unfriendly to not serve users a message after canceling a date? (it redirects to the overview page)**

Yes. Don't do that. Ever. The answer by Benjamin S above elaborates on the reasons why tjat should never be done and points to excellent resources.

**I'm aiming for a somewhat minimal design. And preferably avoid static "date canceled" notices with OK button or X (close).**

You don't have to have a boring, standard display. Have a modal with a great, entertaining or appropriately humorous display that clearly states to the user that the date was cancelled. You mentioned "fading out." That great image can fade in and fade out - what ever is appropriate to your site.